# Lost node-red userid and password

Tags: ibm-cloud, node-red

I've done something dumb...   forgotten the userid and password I set for my node-red application in Bluemix.   The doc says you set the userid/password through environment variables which you access through runtime on the bluemix console. 
I can't seem to get any response from tapping "Runtime" in the sidebar and I can't find any other way to get to the environment variables.   Any ideas please?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the IBM Cloud (former Bluemix) dashboard (https://console.bluemix.net) you first need to find your Node Red app. This is under "Cloud Foundry Apps". Then you click on the entry of your Node Red app and it opens a screen with the app details. On the left should be a navigation panel. Locate "Runtime" and click on it to have the runtime information displayed. In the middle of the top screen you can click on "Environment variables". That should bring up a list of Node Red-specific variables, including the `NODE_RED_PASSWORD`.

Comment: Well, they are not there if you set them as part of the deploy.  But, you can set them there and they will override what is stored in Cloudant.  NODE_RED_PASSWORD and NODE_RED_USERNAME.

Comment: Well, it depends on when Node Red was deployed.

Comment: Thanks for the responses...       Accessing the Environment Variables does, indeed, resolve the problem. I can see my Node-red user/pw settings. However, I'm somewhat perplexed and annoyed because I was only able to do that by switching from my Macbook and Safari to a Windows machine and Firefox.   Clicking "Runtime" in Safari had NO effect but I was able to access Runtime > Environment Variable with no problems in Firefox.